# rvalue reference template argument deduction on operators

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference

On implementation of `operator-` for `is_densevector` classes, I want:

`g = -v;` call the first version of operator (a clone of v will be negative), and:

```
g = -std::move(v);
g = -(v + v);
g = -std::vector<double>({1,2,3});
```

call the second version of operator (vector itself will be negative -- for performance).

The trick is the `!std::is_reference<C>::value` but I am not sure if this is correct. It seems that it is working.

```
//! Return the negative of vector \p v.
template<typename C>
typename std::enable_if<is_densevector<C>::value, C>::type
operator-(const C &v) { return ....; }

//! Return the negative of vector \p v.
template<typename C>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_reference<C>::value && is_densevector<C>::value, C>::type
&&operator-(C &&v) { ....; return std::move(v); }
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/4suqp4 Like this?? Not sure what `is_densevector` does

Comment: Not exactly. black-boxed `is_densevector<C>::value` is true for both `C=std::vector<Integral>` and `C=std::array<Integral,Size>` and more. Also in your example you are not using the 'magic' `C&&v` as function parameter.

Comment: What do you mean I'm not using moving 'magic' as a function parameter? It is using move semantics in the second declaration of the operator. The only difference between the signatures I have posted vs. the ones you have is that yours is templated. Check the link above again and see that it is using move semantics because the vector being assigned is a temporary. Add a print statement to the operators and see: http://ideone.com/4cOh1i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is correct. Since you forgot to ask a real question, I assume you want to check why it works/is necessary? It is necessary because the deduction would yield `const T&` or `T&` for `C&&` in the second case. Through reference collapsing the rvalue-reference is removed. Since this is now ambiguous with the first overload, you need to disambiguate it with the check for `is_reference`.

Note that this is only required for a fully deduced parameter. Another option would be the following, which relies on simple overload resolution and the fact that only the value-type of the vector is deduced, not the whole vector-type:

```
//! Return the negative of vector \p v.
template<typename C>
typename std::enable_if<
    is_densevector<std::vector<C>>::value,
    std::vector<C>
>::type
operator-(const std::vector<C> &v) { return ....; }

//! Return the negative of vector \p v.
template<typename C>
typename std::enable_if<
    is_densevector<std::vector<C>>::value,
    std::vector<C>&&
>::type
operator-(std::vector<C> &&v) { ....; return std::move(v); }
```